# Windows cmd: Parsing output from Ping

Tags: parsing, batch-file, cmd, ping

I would like to execute a ping and, after evaluating the output, return a single line like "0 - check_ping rta=1 loss=0".

0 and 1 being extracted from the ping, of course.

I came this far:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set ip=%1
set num=%2

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('ping -n %num% %ip%') do (
  set line=%%f
  call :processLine
  )

echo 0 myTestService loss=!loss! rta=%rta:~1,-2% further information for myTestService
GOTO:EOF

:processLine
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims==(%%" %%A in ("%line%") do (
    if "%%A" == "Packets: Sent " (
        set loss = %%E
        echo DD%%E
        echo Loss is [!loss!]
    )
    if "%%A" == "Minimum " (
        set rta=%%D
        echo RTA is [!rta:~1,-2!]
    )
)
```

It doesn't work and I asume that it is because of some runtime problems. Obviously I am not a cmd expert, but I read that those for-loops can be tricky in regard of setting variables and accessing them later on.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Warmest regards, freiraum

Comment: You don't have `!loss!`. You defined `!loss !` instead. Remove any spaces around the `=` with the `set` command.

Comment: It would assist us in providing you with more focused help, if you were to [edit] your question to include some example `ping.exe` output, so that we can determine exactly what you're wanting to extract from it. You should also open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, and press the `[ENTER]` key, to learn how to use tokens and delimiters. `"tokens=* delims= "` is wrong, as is `"tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6 delims==(%%"`. You should probably also remove `set line=%%f`, use `call :processLine "%%f"`, and replace `%line%` with `%~1`

Comment: Thank you for the solution, Stephan. And thanks for your constructive additions, Compo.

Comment: uhm, can anybody tell me where to mark an answer as the solution?

Comment: Nobody has answered your question, they've only provided comments which may have assisted you in solving your problem, and/or improving your code. I would advise that you answer the question yourself, showing your new code, and explaining as best you can how it does so. You could after posting it, and sufficient time has elapsed, also mark your own answer as the accepted solution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example which doesn't require delayed expansion, and, for efficiency, uses `find.exe`, to process only the lines from which you wish to extract substrings, and without `call`ing a label:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
If "%~2" == "" Exit /B
Set "loss="
For /F "Tokens=6,8 Delims== " %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\PING.EXE -n %~2 %~1
 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe ","') Do If Not Defined loss (Set "loss=%%H"
) Else Set "rta=%%G"
If Not Defined loss Exit /B
Echo 0 myTestService loss=%loss:~1,-1% rta=%rta:~,-2% further information for myTestService
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code does what I want it to. There are still mistakes ("tokens=* delims= "), but these seem negligible - at least I hope so.

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set ip=%1
set num=%2

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%f in ('ping -n %num% %ip%') do (
  call :processLine "%%f"
  )

echo 0 myTestService loss=!loss:~1! rta=!rta:~0,-2! further information for myTestService
GOTO:EOF

:processLine
for /f "tokens=1,9,11 delims= " %%A in ("%~1") do (
    
    if "%%A" == "Packets:" (
        set loss=%%C
        rem echo Loss is !loss:~1!
    )
    if "%%A" == "Minimum" (
        set rta=%%B
        rem echo RTA is !rta:~0,-2!
    )
)
```

Comment: Well done for following the advice and providing your solution. I have also posted something which you may find useful too.